# iOS simulator does not display TextFields correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, ios-simulator, ios-autolayout

I was designing a login screen for an app. The screen itself is pretty simple. In the Storyboard editor I see:

[image: Looks right]

When I run it on a simulator (iPhone 6s Plus), however, things do not seem right. The textfields do not appear:

[image: No textfields]

If I click into the area where the textfield is supposed to be, I can see it is really there:

[image: The cursor blinks, and I see the keyboard]

I think the issue might end up being just the display, but I want to make sure. Has anyone else had this happen? What was the reason for this issue?

Comment: thats strange!!! Are the two textfields are custom ones or normal text fields?

Comment: try to remove the autolayout or re-define the rules for text field position

Comment: Did text appear when you typed it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, the border was there, the display was so low quality that I couldn't really see it :/

Answer (score 1):

You have set the UITextBorderStyle of your text fields to None. That means they have no visible border. If that isn't what you want, pick a different border style.